# Why React Native Elements Documentation Is Not Accurate? I Did Not Miss a Single Piece Of Instruction

Tags: react-native

I have followed all the documentation of react native elements here
https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/getting_started.html

First, I did the installation itself

```
yarn add react-native-elements
```

Even for vector icons to make sure it can work

```
yarn add react-native-vector-icons
```

Then, link the project

```
react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

However, there is an error while I am trying to use this code as listed under overview of the documentation

```
import { Button, ThemeProvider } from 'react-native-elements';

const MyApp = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider>
      <Button title="Hey!" />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

I do not even change a single code there, but I got this following error when I want to make sure that it works properly.

```
Unable to find module for EventDispatcher

-[RCTCxxBridge moduleForName:lazilyLoadIfNecessary:]
    RCTCxxBridge.mm:462
-[RCTCxxBridge moduleForClass:]
-[RCTBridge(RCTEventDispatcher) eventDispatcher]
-[RCTSettingsManager userDefaultsDidChange:]
__CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__
_CFXRegistrationPost
___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke
-[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:]
_CFXNotificationPost
-[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:]
-[RCTDevSettingsUserDefaultsDataSource _reloadWithDefaults:]
-[RCTDevSettingsUserDefaultsDataSource initWithDefaultValues:]
-[RCTDevSettings init]
__44-[RCTModuleData initWithModuleClass:bridge:]_block_invoke
-[RCTModuleData setUpInstanceAndBridge]
__25-[RCTModuleData instance]_block_invoke
RCTUnsafeExecuteOnMainQueueSync
-[RCTModuleData instance]
__49-[RCTCxxBridge _prepareModulesWithDispatchGroup:]_block_invoke
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
__CFRunLoopRun
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
UIApplicationMain
main
start
```

I really appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried do uninstall and install again? remove `node_modules` and run `npm install`

Comment: this is not an issue from react-native-elements. The error is clear: Failed to load bundle. After trying the suggested solutions, if it doesn't work, then search for that exact error there are related answered questions for that error, now i suggest you delete this question or edit before you start getting down votes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native: Can't run app on iOS correctly "Failed to load bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51867872/react-native-cant-run-app-on-ios-correctly-failed-to-load-bundlehttp-local)

Comment: @MiguelNeves I did it but still get the same error.

Comment: @MaStErNeWbIeI tried to follow that question the error is still exists. It comes with different circumstances. The code that I used comes from its documentation and I did all the installation and even linking process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When installing packages for React-Native most of the time you need to clear the cache and or build folders for the new changes to get compiled correctly.

Try these commands within your apps folder;

```
// ** Clear caches and update pods (IOS)
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf /node_modules && rm -rf /$TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf /$TMPDIR/npm-* && rm -rf /ios/build && rm -rf /ios/Pods && pod cache clean --all && pod repo update && cd ios/ && pod install && cd ../ && npm install

// ** clear caches without updating pods (IOS)
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf /node_modules && rm -rf /$TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf /$TMPDIR/npm-* && rm -rf /ios/build && npm install

// ** clear caches (Android)
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf /node_modules && rm -rf /$TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf /$TMPDIR/npm-* && rm -rf /android/build && rm -rf /android/app/build && npm cache verify && npm install && cd android/ && ./gradlew clean && cd ../

// ** Clear caches (iOS & Android)
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf /node_modules && rm -rf /$TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf /$TMPDIR/npm-* && rm -rf /ios/build && rm -rf /android/build && rm -rf /android/app/build && rm -rf /ios/Pods && pod cache clean --all && npm install && ./android/gradlew clean -p ./android/ && cd ../ios/ && pod install && cd ../
```

Your original question of why the documentation is not accurate;

Some packages do inform you to clear your caches etc, however, your terminal output does actually provide you with a link and steps on how to fix your issue

```
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`. (null))
```

So there for the documentation doesn't really need to tell you this as well.

Comment: Hi, I have followed it but got another error. I edited my question and also I have read this following question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54883304/unable-to-find-module-for-eventdispatcher-react-native

Unfortunately, there is no answer.

Comment: Hey, @RadenBagus this is a different issue your facing now. You should be creating a new issue not updating this one as you go along

Comment: sure, I will try to find the answer first before creating another issue. Thank you 